# Can't git aws.push to elastic beanstalk with ruby repo

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've gone through all the steps in the different tutorials.

I've gotten my elastic beanstalk instance to create via +eb init+
and  I have set my path correctly.

Then I did a 
    git .init
and tried a 
    git aws.push 
and got the error of :

```
error: cannot run .git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push: No such file or directory
fatal: While expanding alias 'aws.elasticbeanstalk.push':       
.git/AWSDevTools/aws.elasticbeanstalk.push': No such file or directory
```

Now I had cloned this project at first from another git repo so I then did an

```
eb stop
```

spun down the instance and then did a

```
rm -rf .git
```

on the working directory to clear out any items that  would be left in there from the previous clone.

I then did the

```
eb init
```

again so all the .git info would be re-regenerated

I have even followed the steps from http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_Ruby_rails.html 
and  did a

```
git init && git add -A && git commit -m "Initial commit"
```

then once I tried to do the:

```
git aws.push
```

I was greeted with the same same error message as before.

Granted this is my first beanstalk instance I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. Are you only allowed to run the git commands from the same directory where you downloaded the CLI to?

**UPDATE** I did find another link that said to do  this step:

```
sh /home/elasticbeanstalk-cli/AWSDevTools/Linux/AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh
```

But all that did was give me this message:

```
sh /home/coder/eb/AWSDevTools/Linux/AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh 
/home/coder/eb/AWSDevTools/Linux/AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh: 18:      
/home/coder/eb/AWSDevTools/Linux/AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh: Bad substitution
```

*OS: Linux (Ubuntu / LTS 12.04)*

Comment: I've gotten a response from Amazon in their forum which has solved this issue: _We've just uncovered a problem where the installer doesn't work properly if invoked using a non-bash implementation of "sh" -- it's possible that you're seeing the same problem._  The solution was to replace **sh** with **bash** when invoking the shell script that initialized the repository.  `$ bash path/to/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3/AWSDevTools/Linux/AWSDevTools-RepositorySetup.sh`

Comment: Thats' correct. The current version of RepositorySetup.sh has some bashisms. 

From my communication with them, the next version is going to be published between mid/late January. A workaround is to call bash explicitly

Answer (score 2):

It says that the file does not exists, but the error is caused because ruby is not installed. So if you are using Linux (Ubuntu), you should install it using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install ruby
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem. But I am Python Developer and elasticbeanstalk-cli developed by ruby.I just installed the ruby in my system all problems are solved.